# Jenkins, possible to runparallel builds on one machine?

Tags: jenkins

I currently only have one machine (physical, not virtualized) available which I could use to run Jenkins on. I am wondering, without creating virtualized master-slave environments, is it possible to have Jenkins to execute several builds/tests/deployments, etc. with only one machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set how many executors you want to run simoutineously. You can change this setting in Jenkins > Configure System > # of executors.

Comment: Just make sure your build/tests/deployments etc don't have hardcoded paths e.g. a test script that expects output to go into a directory and starts by clearing out any old content in that dir will not work if a second executor starts another test that clears out the directory.